# Flex Application as Singleton (Flash Builder 4.6, Eclipse)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, singleton, adobe

I have one Flex application which I launched via Eclipse. 
Now if I open a new tab (e.g in Firefox) with these commands:

```
            var url:String = 'DeepLinkingProject.html#view=1';
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            navigateToURL(urlReq,'_blank');
```

I have two instances of the same application. But I do not want that.
I want that these two share the same application instance and if I update one component in one browser-tab I want the other browser-tab to be synchronized.

Is this possible?!

test example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*" xmlns:test="test.*" creationComplete="init()" >
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
                             import flash.net.navigateToURL;

        import mx.events.BrowserChangeEvent;
        import mx.managers.BrowserManager;
        import mx.managers.IBrowserManager;
        import mx.utils.URLUtil;


        private var bm:IBrowserManager;
        private var isParsing:Boolean;
        private var title:String;

        private function init():void{
            bm = BrowserManager.getInstance();
            bm.init("","Start");
            bm.addEventListener(BrowserChangeEvent.BROWSER_URL_CHANGE, parseURL);
            callLater(parseURL);

        }

        private function parseURL():void{
            //isParsing = true;
            //var o:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(bm.fragment);
            //if (o.view == undefined)
            //  o.view = "Home";
            //bm.setTitle(title);
            //isParsing = false;
        }

        private function updateU():void{
            var fragments:String = "";
            fragments = bm.fragment;

            btnA.label = fragments;

           /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           // e.g. After this call, a new Browser-Tab gets opened and the
                            // Button Component should have the same Label content

            navigateToURL(new URLRequest('DeepLinkingProject.html'));
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                           }

        private function changeUrl():void{
            bm.setFragment('view=B');
            updateU();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:VBox>
    <s:Label id="header" text="Application started without Parameters"/>
    <mx:HBox borderStyle="solid">
        <s:Button id="btnA" click="changeUrl()"/>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loaded flash applications can communicate via [LocalConnection](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Local+Connections). So you can send messages from one application to the other and copy behavior.

Comment: you can use it for loaded swfs in browser

Comment: Ok. If I do it that way , it is my job to synchronize everything. Is there no way to have a single instance of an application which can be accessed through multiple windows or browser-tabs?!

Comment: No, it's impossible. And yes, you'll need to synchronize everything... Are you sure you need that functionality?

Comment: Ok. And are there any other alternatives to accomplish this?! Yeah we really need that feature.

Comment: That's the only idea that come to my mind. You can try wait for other ideas from someone